# InvalidChangeBatch: [RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name x. is not permitted as it conflicts with other records with the same DNS name in zone x.]

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to write a terraform module that creates Route53 entries based for a geolocalised app.
My code seems to work fine for the first time but then it breaks with the error in the title.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.3.0"
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "cdn_cname" {
  zone_id         = "${var.route53_zone_id}"
  name            = "${var.domain}"
  type            = "CNAME"
  ttl             = 300
  allow_overwrite = true
  set_identifier  = "${var.envName}Id"
  records         = ["${var.records}"]


  geolocation_routing_policy {
    continent     = "${var.continent}"
    country       = "${var.country}"
  }
}
```

The error seems explicit enough but whey I try to manually create a CNAME with the same record as another one it seems to work fine. What's the difference between them?

Comment: That typically means you are trying to create a CNAME record when an existing record eg A record already exists. This could also mean there is an existing TXT record for that domain name, which can't co-exist with a CNAME record.

Comment: Yea you're right. There were both an A and a TXT record with the same domain. What I'm seeing now is that they keep creating even after manually deleting them. This is weird as the type is hardcoded to CNAME. I've even tried setting ```create_before_destroy = true``` but still they are created before the CNAME. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What does the TXT record contain? Do you have kubernetes external-dns running somewhere in your env? You will need to figure out what is creating those records and stop it, it's not coming from the code you posted.